# iOS device not identified correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm facing a user reported bug that I'm trying to make sense of.

Users are reporting that the layout of the app changed, although nothing has changed in the code. I've checked many devices (both physical and simulators) and I can't reproduce it.

After viewing the screenshots they've sent, it seems that they are seeing the screen as it was designed in the InterfaceBuilder without the modifications of the constraints made by in code according to the specific device.

I'm checking the device type using methods such as:

```
public static bool isIphoneXR
    {
        get
        {
            return
                UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom
                == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone
                && UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height
                * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 1792;
        }
    }
```

My question is are there any conditions/situations which can cause this method to return a false negative so the app won't know which device its running on?

Comment: this seems like a really bad way to determine the device type - why not use the helper class from Essentials?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?tabs=ios

Comment: Thanks! It's an old method I'm using, I will try what you've referenced. Can you think of a scenario in which it won't work? (I'm trying to reproduce this bug)

Comment: Does the app have the ability to rotate? If so, there you go, that's the reason. Rotation swaps the screen Height with its Width, so the test fails.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's portrait only. But I suspect it might be related to the zoom settings.

Comment: Use just `UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height == 896` - will not be zoom related

Comment: It returns 812 when I change the settings to zoomed

Comment: Ah.. sorry.. my mistake. Try  `UIScreen.MainScreen.NativeBounds.Height == 1792`

Comment: Seems confusing, are you not using autolayout in the interface builder?.